# NPM Workspaces: Share `*.d.ts` TypeScript definition files between workspaces

Tags: typescript, npm-workspaces

I have a TypeScript monorepo with NPM Workspaces.

There are two packages; A and B.

I need type definitions from A inside B.

I have added reference to A's definition file in package B's `tsconfig.json`.
However it doesn't feel right:

```json
{
  "include": ["../a/types.d.ts", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

It's the relative reference I don't like. I expected it to work with `a/types.d.ts` as "a" is the package name — but it doesn't.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: did you solve it?